# change price from listbox

Tags: html, listbox

I want add this listbox to my website.For example If i select Volvo price must show 10$, if i select Audi price must show 20$

```html
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Price panel from my website

```html
<div class="tovar-price-block">
<div class="price-block-head"><span class="tovar-price">[xfvalue_price]<span id="azn">M</span></span></div>
[xfgiven_old-price]<div class="tovar-discount  green">
```

Comment: Where do you want to show the price?

Comment: https://steam.az/odenis-kartlari/14-google-play-gift-card.html

Answer (score 0):

Add event handler to your `select`

```
<select onchange="change()">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

then you have to define the function `change()` and update the `price` wherever you want to.